# Is compiling on a different machine possible?

Tags: opengl

Is compiling OpenGL program, made on a VirtualBox Machine Windows XP, possible on a diffrent machine, for example, if I made the program on a Virtual Machine and wanted to send the compilation process to Ubuntu which is the host.

I'm asking this, because I was searching for a method to use my host's GPU for Virtual Machine, but I wasn't able to do that, couldn't find any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

> I was searching for a method to use my host's GPU for Virtual Machine

The location where and on what OS the program has been built has nothing to do with this particular issue. OpenGL is just an API specification and when you compile a program to use OpenGL it will just follow the API but not contain one blip of code that actually does talk with a GPU. That's what drivers and the OpenGL implementations they deliver do.

What you need is a driver for within Virtual Machine, that exposes a OpenGL API and passes the commands on to the hosts GPU.

Comment: That was actually off-topic, I meant that I tried plenty methods, but yes, I do need some sort of a driver that does that, but can't find anything, do You know any possible way to compile the code from Virtual Machine without copying it to the host ?

Comment: @user1494173: You don't need a OpenGL driver to be installed just for compilation. All compilers for Windows ship with GL/gl.h and opengl32.lib. And for a virtualized Linux host you install the Mesa development files. You can compile and link your programs, but when starting them they either refuse to work, or will drop into a software rasterizer mode, which is not GPU accelerated; unless you install a cross VM boundary driver.

Comment: I do know that Windows ships with gl.h, the problem is, it ships with gl.h version 2.1, which is not what I want, I actually need OpenGL version 4.3. What about this cross VM boundary driver ? I googled it and didn't find anything satisfying.

Now I'm actually trying to copy the files from linux to windows, but that is probably a bit retarded, I'm really running out of options and will probably have to install windows ; (

Comment: @user1494173: Compiling has **nothing** to do with the driver. You'd have the very same problem, even if you were not in a virtual machine. BTW, it's only OpenGL-1.1 or 1.4 you've got available, probably. The solution however is the same as for everyone who wants to compile for OpenGL-2 or later under Windows: You must use the extension loader mechanism to load later OpenGL functionality at runtime. I suggest to use the GLEW library for that. Just Google for GLEW and maybe add "StackOverflow" to the search. It's been asked hundreds of times.

Comment: Oh My Goodness, I've made a full of myself, you are right, the problem was, that I didn't link GLFW properly, actually didn't link opengl32.lib which enables GLFW to use some of its functions ; )

Sorry for your trouble and thanks for help. Oh, Windows XP really ships with OpenGL 2.1, check it if you want ; )

Thanks very much!

Comment: @user1494173: Windows XP definitely doesn't ship with OpenGL-2.1. Heck even Windows Vista's / 7's basic OpenGL support goes only up to version OpenGL-1.4. Anything beyond works only with original vendor drivers being installed, even if the GPU was capable of it.